# Shadow variable when linting

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, lint

When linting the following code:

```
  public doStuf = (): Promise<null> => {
    const data = new Stuff(this.value);
    if (this.state === 'test') {
        data.mail = {
          object: label,
          files: this.dropppedFiles || []
        };
        return this.validate = (data) => null;
    } else {
        return this.validate = (data) => null;
    }
  }
```

I'm passing `doStuff()` as promise to a child component that's why I need to keep the context with `this.validate = (data) => null;`

(There's maybe a more elegant way of doing things?)

I get

> Shadowed variable: 'data'

I tried unsing `let` instead of `const` but lint complains again about `data is never modified, use const instead`

All my tests pass, and the component works as expected. How do I get rid of this error?

EDIT:
What works is
`this.validate = (boo = data) => null;`

How horrible is that?

EDIT:

I actually want to pass parameters to the validate function and keep the arrow function structure at the same time. Something like:

```
this.validate(data) = () => null;
```

Comment: Just don't call the other variable `data`. `return this.validate = (whatever) => {} `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Sense of 'No Shadowed Variable' tslint Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853057/making-sense-of-no-shadowed-variable-tslint-warning) - the lint is simply telling you that you're hiding a variable by defining another with the same name. That won't necessarily cause issues, but it can make it easy to introduce bugs in some cases.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Linked post doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
this.validate = (data) => null;
```

`this.validate` is a function with one parameter, `data`, which means you can no longer reference the original `data` variable.

If you call this parameter something else it will run fine.

```
this.validate = (param) => null;
```

**EDIT**

From your comment it sounds like you don't want to define but call the `this.validate` function. In which case just do

```
this.validate(data);
```

Comment: But it used to be this.validate(data). I need to pass data as parameter

Comment: @gyc: The value of the parameter passes to `this.validate` will be the same, regardless of what you name it.

Comment: You're not passing `data` this way. You're just declating `this.validate` as a method that takes one parameter, which you can call whatever you want.

Comment: I understand. How do I pass data as parameter while keeping the structure this.validate = () => null; ? I need this structure to keep the right context when passing doStuff() to another component

Comment: I accept the answer because it led me to avoiding the problem in the first place (which was in a unit test)